# Programatically specify lazy loading for many-to-one in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading, criteria-api, many-to-one

I am using Hibernate 3.6 with Spring 3.0.5.

I have the following mapping for a User object

```
<class name="foo.User" table="FOO_USER">
    <id  column="USER_ID" name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>


    <property name="firstName" column="FIRST_NAME" type="java.lang.String" length="100"/>
    ...
    <many-to-one name="organization" column="ORGANIZATION_ID class="foo.Organization" not-null="true" update="false" />
    ...
```

The User has a many-to-one relationship with Organization. Usually, I want that relationship to be eagerly loaded, so the mapping sticks with the default setting of lazy=false (by not specifying anything).

There is a certain case where I do not want to eagerly load the Organization. I tried specifying this with a Criteria

```
(User)getSession().createCriteria(User.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("id",id))
            .setFetchMode("organization", FetchMode.SELECT)
            .uniqueResult();
```

But the fetch mode is being ignored. Hibernate still eagerly loads the Organization relationship. I've been knocking my head against this for a few hours. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always best to leave associations mapped as lazy and use fetching strategies to tune performance. I don't believe there's a way to map something as lazy and then make it un-lazy in a particular instance. Certainly fetch=select won't do it, as that doesn't imply anything about laziness. See [section 21.1 of "Improving Performance"](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html) in the reference manual for an explanation of the concepts.

Comment: Agreed.  Keep things LAZY and override when you need to do so.  Associations should only be EAGER in cases where you are absolutely sure that you will always want the association populated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies. I agree that in general relationships should be kept LAZY. In this case, however, I almost always need the relationship to be EAGER, except in one circumstance. It is too bad there is no way to programatically make the relationship lazy.  As for fetch=select: I had originally used fetchmode=lazy, but in hibernate 3.6, it is deprecated. The javadoc says to use SELECT instead. (I originally did try with fetchmode=LAZY, but that did not work either.)

Comment: Actually, if there is no way to programmatically make a relationship LAZY, why is there a FetchMode.LAZY value?

Comment: I believe the deprecation of that value answers the question. I'd assume it doesn't really make the fetching lazy, but makes it use a select fetch.

Answer (score 1):

FetchType can be set programatically using fetchProfiles

e.g.: Consider there is an Employee class and it has two child classes Address and Department Fetch profiles for these can be set in the Employee class.

```
@FetchProfiles({ @FetchProfile(name = "emp_address", fetchOverrides = { @FetchProfile.FetchOverride(entity = Employee.class, association = "addresses", mode = FetchMode.JOIN) }), @FetchProfile(name = "emp_department", fetchOverrides = { @FetchProfile.FetchOverride(entity = Employee.class, association = "departments", mode = FetchMode.JOIN) })}) public class Employee {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) private Set addresses;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) private Set departments; }
```

You can enable the fetchprofile When you are retrieve Employee record. If the fetch profile is enable then the child objects are eagerly fetch because you are doing a join

```
session.enableFetchProfile("emp_address");
session.enableFetchProfile("emp_department");
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class); 
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY); 
List employees = criteria.list();
```